# Android - check an EditText input box each type the user types in a character

Tags: android, android-edittext, listener, actionlistener

I am trying to check each time a user types a character into a `EditText` box.

Is there some type of `OnChangeListener`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [textChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)) to detect if the `edittext` values is changed upon clicking from the input keyboard

**sample:**

```
edditext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
            //s is the current character in the eddittext after it is changed
    }
});
```

Comment: ah, i was looking in the set section, Ill give that a shot and let you know

Comment: Yes, it is strange that this is one of the very few listeners in Android where apparently multiple instances are allowed.

Comment: am i able to intercept the value and change it before it is placed into the EditText?

Comment: @K3NN3TH use the `beforeTextChanged` if you want to change it before it is placed in the eddittext. and make sure you call setText to the eddittext

Comment: damn, had to `removelistener`, `settext`, `addlistener` and did that in `onTextchange` `beforetextchange` does not give me the value of `softkey` pressed

Answer (score 2):

@Rod_Algonquin's answer (accepted) mentioned that the `s` parameter is all the characters in the EditText. What I was looking for was a way to get the specific text added, so I just adjusted what was mentioned above.

```
private void setTextChangedListener(EditText editText) {
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String inputString = String.valueOf(s.subSequence(start, start + count));
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }
```

`inputString` is the actual text added to the EditText.